# How can Nintendo cartoon Captain N use video game characters owned by different companies without those companies appearing in the show's copyright?

Tags: copyright, copyright-notice

Captain N was a late 80s cartoon which uses characters and settings from several games that are playable on the Nintendo Entertainment System console. Some of these are Nintendo owned, but there is a significant amount not owned by Nintendo like Mega Man, Castlevania, Tetris, Dragon Warrior and Final Fantasy that appear but the companies who own these games don't show up in the credits or even in the copyright section of the DVD i own.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E8jxeetnZ9U

As you can see from the link, the show claims that all of the elements in the show are owned by Nintendo/Nintendo of America despite that not being true.

Comment: Because that's the deal they made? I don't see how this is answerable except by finding a copy of the contract they formed, which is not the purpose of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

### Attribution is not a legal requirement

If company A owns IP (copyright and trademarks in this case), they can licence it to company N on whatever terms are mutually acceptable. They may require company N to attribute their IP or they may not.